# How to disable the tax amount of each product which has tax as disabled in magento?

Tags: magento

[image]

In this screenshot, it shows a product which I have tax class as None in the admin panel but it is showing a default tax as in the screenshot. Can anyone say how to disable that tax value ?

Comment: Did you try setting the Display Zero Tax Subtotal to No?
Administration> System > Configuration > Tax > Shopping cart display settings > Display Zero tax subtotal.

Comment: ss..its already set as zero..

Answer (score 0):

Go to system->configuration->tax->shopping cart display setting. Now change the Shopping Cart Display setting according to screenshot.
[image]